# Django templates unexpectedly omit results from Elasticsearch

Tags: django, elasticsearch

Django templates seemed to omit part of results returned by `Elasticsearch_dsl`.

The Elasticsearch low-level python client works fine.
If it is just `{{source}}` without "for loops", it works fine as well.

The code is simply:

```
{% for item in source %}
{{item}}
{% endif %}
```

Expected results rendered by Django templates:

`{'_index': 'search', '_type': '_doc', '_id': '1', sentence:'abc'}`

Actual results:

`{'_index': 'search', '_type': '_doc', '_id':...}`

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible you have a text-overflow CSS property set to ellipsis in your template? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

Comment: Thank you for the info. I don't have any CSS in the file.

Comment: You're welcome.  I think you'll have to put more code/examples/explanation into your question.